# Can I import vector graphics file, such as illustrator generated(*.ai files), into flex3?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, import

Can I import vector graphics file, such as illustrator generated(*.ai files), into flex3?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the answer is no. But illustrator can export vector as a swf or svg file that you can import into flex.

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you need to do is create skings that can be imported into Flex.  To export the graphics as swf files you will need the [Flex Component Kit for Flash CS3](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/entitlement/index.cfm?e=flex_skins).  This article gives a good overview of the process  - http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/skins_styles_04.html